# REST API: How can I restrict a custom post type to only be accessible by authenticated users?

Tags: custom-post-types, api, capabilities, user-access, rest-api

I have a `custom post type` configured to be accessible via the [WP Rest API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org).

How do I lock the access to this `custom post type` so that only the authenticated users can perform `GET` requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found a snippet that do exactly that.
It's from Daniel Bachhuber, the API developer.

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'restx_logged_out', 'Sorry, you must be logged in to make a request.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
});
```

This is posted in his [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielbachhuber/8f92af4c6a8db784771c) on GitHub.

Comment: select your answer as correct answer if it solved your problem.